# What is the kubernetes equivalent of docker inspect?

Tags: kubernetes

When a docker container is running it is sometimes helpful to look at *runtime configuration*.
What is the equivalent command for kubernetes?

I did a search on so for this and came up with some similar questions:   See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=What+is+the+kubernetes+equivalent, but not this question.

- [What's the kubectl equivalent of docker exec bash in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67081888/whats-the-kubectl-equivalent-of-docker-exec-bash-in-kubernetes)
- [Docker volume and kubernetes volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62312227/docker-volume-and-kubernetes-volume)

Comment: see here (for need of container labels) https://stackoverflow.com/q/53964894/1747983 , no option yet.

Answer (score 5):

Kubernetes is a container orchestrator, so you'll not find container-level commands.

You can check the container logs:

```
kubectl logs pod-name

Mon Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 2001 INFO 0
Mon Jan  1 00:00:01 UTC 2001 INFO 1
Mon Jan  1 00:00:02 UTC 2001 INFO 2
```

You can describe a pod to see pod details, as well as possible pull image errors:

```
kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment-1006230814-6winp

Name:       nginx-deployment-1006230814-6winp
Namespace:  default
Node:       kubernetes-node-wul5/10.240.0.9
Start Time: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 01:39:49 +0000
Labels:     app=nginx,pod-template-hash=1006230814
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"nginx-deployment-1956810328","uid":"14e607e7-8ba1-11e7-b5cb-fa16" ...
Status:     Running
IP:     10.244.0.6
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/nginx-deployment-1006230814
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   docker://90315cc9f513c724e9957a4788d3e625a078de84750f244a40f97ae355eb1149
    Image:      nginx
    Image ID:       docker://6f62f48c4e55d700cf3eb1b5e33fa051802986b77b874cc351cce539e5163707
    Port:       80/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:  Guaranteed
      memory:   Guaranteed
    Limits:
      cpu:  500m
      memory:   128Mi
    Requests:
      memory:       128Mi
      cpu:      500m
    State:      Running
      Started:      Thu, 24 Mar 2016 01:39:51 +0000
    Ready:      True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:        <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5kdvl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Initialized   True
  Ready         True
  PodScheduled  True
Volumes:
  default-token-4bcbi:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-4bcbi
    Optional:   false
QoS Class:      Guaranteed
Node-Selectors: <none>
Tolerations:    <none>
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                    SubobjectPath       Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                    -------------       --------    ------      -------
  54s       54s     1   {default-scheduler }                        Normal      Scheduled   Successfully assigned nginx-deployment-1006230814-6winp to kubernetes-node-wul5
  54s       54s     1   {kubelet kubernetes-node-wul5}  spec.containers{nginx}  Normal      Pulling     pulling image "nginx"
  53s       53s     1   {kubelet kubernetes-node-wul5}  spec.containers{nginx}  Normal      Pulled      Successfully pulled image "nginx"
  53s       53s     1   {kubelet kubernetes-node-wul5}  spec.containers{nginx}  Normal      Created     Created container with docker id 90315cc9f513
  53s       53s     1   {kubelet kubernetes-node-wul5}  spec.containers{nginx}  Normal      Started     Started container with docker id 90315cc9f513
```

If you need see details about a container, use the docker client or whatever other container runtime client for this purpose.

Comment: I would argue that the equivalent of `docker inspect` is probably `kubectl get -o json <podname>`, which will return a JSON document describing the pod, much like `docker inspect` returns a JSON blog describing the container.

Comment: @larsks Oh true, this command has some more information and the output type is like the docker inspect. I didn't know this, good to know hehe.

Comment: @larsks You should add that as an answer.